# Direct post / message from external webpage

Tags: facebook, external, message, contacts, facebook-wall

I want users of our website to be able to contact us via facebook, and instead of just linking to our page where users have to manually select post on wall or message, I would like it to be the case that when they click the facebook 'f' on the site, it automatically directs them immediately to post on our wall or indeed to send a message to us.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Ross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about linking them to

```
https://www.facebook.com/messages/<YourPage>
```

That page automatically pops up a box to send you a message if they haven't sent you a message before. If they have, then it will show the conversation and allow them to reply at the bottom as usual.

Comment: Thanks Timm, very simple after all! That's great